# How can I marshal a nested list of links in Flask-Restful?

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I would like to marshal an object so that I get a response containing a list of links using Url, List and Nested from the Flask-Restful api.

```
job_link_fields = {
    'href': restful.fields.Url('ep1', absolute=False),
    'rel': restful.fields.Url('ep2', absolute=False)
}

job_fields = {
    'name': restful.fields.String,
    'links': restful.fields.List(restful.fields.Nested(job_link_fields))
}

class JobDao():
    def __init__(self, id, job):
        self.name = job['name']
        self.links = [{'rel': 'jobs', 'id': id},
                      {'rel': 'jobs', 'id': id}]

class Job(restful.Resource):

    @marshal_with(job_fields)
    def get(self, id):
        return JobDao(id, jobs[id-1])
```

But in the Url class, I need to specify the endpoint in the constructor which prevents me from adding differend job_link_fields in the List. How can I create a list of link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61376040/flask-restful-how-to-document-response-body-with-fields-dict/61438775#61438775